# Use Material UI autocomplete in freeSolo mode with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use the Material UI's autocomplete in free solo mode as a kind of a combo-input. The user should be able to either select a suggested option via autocomplete or if no option is available, the input value should be used as the final form value.

The problem:

Case one: autocomplete works and suggests options that can be selected and are submitted but when the input has a custom value it does not get submitted.

https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-free-solo-case-1-i7kin?file=/demo.js

Case two: selected options from autocomplete and custom input values are submitted BUT the autocomplete dropdown does not show suggestions anymore, but rather stays open the whole time the input is selected

https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-free-solo-case-2-uk9db?file=/demo.js

I could live with case two because my autocomplete lists have just a few options, but if anyone has some hint or a solution I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are using the `freeSolo`, but you didn't add the `autoSelect` option, so the problem with your code is that when the `input` lose focus - the value is still the old one. The reason here is that you are using a controlled component, but the controller is the react-hook-form.

You can have two options here:

1. Add the `autoSelect`, so even when the user lose focus on the input - the current value will be the value of the autocomplete.
2. Require the user to hit `enter` in order to save the value that he currently have. (You can use the `clearOnBlur` option for that).

Here is the implementation of the first option:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="autocomplete"
  freeSolo
  autoSelect
  options={["option1", "option2", "another option"]}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="freeSolo"
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
    />
  )}
/>
```

And a working example (based on your codesandbox): https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-freesolo-with-auto-value-on-blur-e2smn?file=/demo.js

Comment: Big thanks, this worked! Do you know the Material UI autocomplete or how did you get to this solution?

Comment: I do know the material ui autocomplete, but I also had to play with it a bit to find the right way to solve this.

Comment: Is there a solution without option #2 

2. Require the user to hit enter in order to save the value that he currently have. (You can use the clearOnBlur option for that).

I see the behavior where if value is some part (substring) of the entire string, user have to hit Enter key for the AutoComplete to take it.