# Mui dropdown open after 3 input characters but dropdown not closing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I want to close this Mui dropdown when I clicked an option. Currently I can't close
Is there any way to close this

```
<Autocomplete
  id='select-status'
  freeSolo
  options={['Active', 'InActive']}
  onInputChange={(e, newValue) =>
    setPlateFormData({ ...plateFormData, IsActive: newValue })
  }
  value={plateFormData.IsActive}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <sdkMui.TextField {...params} size='small' label='Status' name='IsActive' />
  )}
/>;
```

I want to close the dropdown when I click an option

Comment: You can try setting [disableCloseOnSelect](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-prop-disableCloseOnSelect) to false . This is normally the default value but there may be some code in your application that is overriding this.

Comment: Also, try removing "freeSolo". [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549813/use-material-ui-autocomplete-in-freesolo-mode-with-react-hook-form)